# Entire system starts malfunctioning after empyting bin

Tags: rm

So recently I wiped the trash bin folder with the `sudo rm /bin` command because it was getting filled up with a lot of junk that I didn't put there. Now I can't boot and get error messages.

I don't get how empyting the bin can break the system... Did I do something wrong? Or did I accidentally wipe a different folder from bin?

Comment: It stands for `binary`

Answer (score 4):

`/bin` is not a trash folder but an essential part of Ubuntu. By removing it you effectively destroyed your Ubuntu installation. To fix the damage you'll have to reinstall Ubuntu. If you have important files stored on your system which you still need and for which you don't have a backup, get professional help to try and salvage them first.

Comment: As above - I’m afraid you’ve deleted your *binaries* folder, nothing to do with trash. If you can’t afford / access professional recovery services, by booting into a live usb session (‘try Ubuntu’), you’ll probably be able to find documents in your home folder to back up before you reinstall Ubuntu.